# Eager loading in nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_profile_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :profile_categories, through: :profile_profile_categories
end

class ProfileCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile_subject
end

class ProfileSubject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_categories, dependent: :destroy
end

class ProfileProfileCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile_category
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

How can I load Profile and eager load ProfileCategory and ProfileSubject?

`Profile.includes(profile_categories: :profile_subject)` doesn't work.

Gem bullet show next notification in browser:

```
user: verrom N+1 Query detected ProfileSubject => [:profile_categories] Add to your finder: :includes => [:profile_categories]
```

And in server logs I can see a lot of queries to table ProfileCategory like:

```
ProfileCategory Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "profile_categories".* FROM "profile_categories" WHERE "profile_categories"."profile_subject_id" = $1  [["profile_subject_id", 4]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try once  below

```
Profile.includes(profile_profile_categories: [{ profile_category: :profile_subject } ], :profile_categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your SQL log it seems that `ProfileSubject` is loaded correctly. Add what you see from bullet gem.

`Profile.includes(:profile_categories, profile_categories: :profile_subject)`

This should work